# Uploading images for Wordpress in AWS Elastic Beanstalk application

Tags: wordpress, images, amazon-aws, cloud-hosting, amazon-s3

How do I go about uploading images in an AWS Elastic Beanstalk Wordpress Application?

I am using the high-availability method from [this tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/php-hawordpress-tutorial.html).

It's a large WooCommerce website and I have 2gigs worth of product images that would usually be stored in the wp-content/uploads folder. There is a max upload file size on an elastic beanstalk instance version, so I'm assuming I will have to upload the images via FTP.

I now know that I have an S3 bucket linked with my EB instance that stores all of my files in the background. In the S3 management console, I can see my zip files of the current instance version, but how to I add to it? I'm totally new to this, but is the S3 bucket what I have to FTP into in order to upload these images? If so, how do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to download the application add your photos on the correct directory and upload and deploy

**1. First, download the latest version zip file**

- Elastic Beanstalk Beanstalk - Application Versions
- Click on the source code link to download

**2. Unzip the files**

- copy the photos on the correct folder.

**3. Zip and Upload**

- Compress the files *make sure to select all files from the unzip folder - Don't compress the folder itselft*
- Under Application versions click upload and select your new zip file *make sure to type a version label*

**4. Deploy**

- Use the checkbox to select the uploaded version and click deploy
- Give it a few minutes while it uploads and sets up the new version.